# Error in calling php function the second time through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, html-table

```
<?php 
function get()
{
    if(isset($_POST['enquire'])
     {

            $flying_to = $_POST['flying_to'];
            $str = "<b>".$flying_to."</b>";
            echo $str;
    }   
}  
?>

<script>
    function table()
    {
    var a = '<?php get(); ?>';
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = a;
    }
</script>
```

I am calling a php function through a javascript but I am able to see just a constant predefined value which I used earlier for testing purposes. I want to actually create a table in HTML and in that I am appending it using javascript and fetching the data from database using php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 1st thing I would change is going from `echo $str;` to `return $str;` and from `'<?php get(); ?>` to `'<?php echo get(); ?>`.

Comment: I tried using but the data is not reflecting in the webpage

Comment: A `var_dump($_POST)` within your `get()` method might reveals why it is not showing what you expect.

Comment: First Check if your `$_POST['enquire']` is having value or not !

Comment: _"I am calling a php function through a javascript"_ - no, you are not. Check the explanation inside the duplicate.

Comment: PHP runs _first_ when your page is being loaded, _before_ your JavaScript - that only executes after the page has loaded into the browser. Anything your PHP get() function outputs will effectievly be hard-coded into the JS code which gets rendered to the browser. You can use the browser's View Source feature to see what I mean - you'll notice that `<?php get(); ?>` is nowhere to be seen - it's been executed, and its output (if any) has been output into the page, in the middle of the JS code. To call it again from JS, you'd need to use AJAX to make a new HTTP request to the server & PHP script.